# Snowflake connector with confluent cloud region error

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

I was working with the confluent and trying to connect MySQL as the source and it did connect but when I tried to connect with snowflake it gives me a region error.

here is the connector config in confluent

```
Connector Summary
Name
SnowflakeSinkConnector_0
Connector Class
SnowflakeSink
Topics
MysqlJConfluent.source.user_details
Max Tasks
1
input.data.format
JSON
kafka.api.key
****************
kafka.api.secret
****************************************************************
snowflake.url.name
https://*****.europe-west2.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com:443
snowflake.user.name
admin
snowflake.private.key
*************************************************************************************************
snowflake.database.name
DEMO_DB
snowflake.schema.name
PUBLIC
tasks.max
1
```

here is the error:

```
Please make sure the cloud region is supported by Snowflake and Kafka cluster and Snowflake database are in the same region.
```

I tried with the same region but no use.
Please help me out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: To confirm, your kafka cluster is in the same region/platform as your Snowflake account?  This appears to be Europe-West2 on GCP per your connection string.

Comment: This is not a Snowflake error. Have you checked with Confluence support?

Answer (score 0):

These appear to be good instructions on setting up that connector: https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-snowflake-sink.html#step-1-launch-your-ccloud-cluster. I hope this points you in the right direction.